# No puedo traducir las fechas en theme de Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

Tengo el siguiente sitio en Wordpress donde tengo fichas de doctores con los días en inglés y quiero cambiarlos a español:
http://comproautosusados.com/centrolerner2016/horarios/
Probé con el Loco Translate, probé editando los archivos .po directamente e incluso me metí a revisar los archivos php del theme y no he podido dar con la solución. He traducido lo más que he podido y ahora lo tengo ahí como lo ven ahora: "de MONDAY hasta THRUSDAY".
Encontré en los achivos template del theme uno llamado practice.php que es de donde se genera el html de estas fichas de doctores y tengo algo así:

```
$days = '';
if ($object->get('days')) {
$days = $object->get('days');
if (count($days) > 1) {
$last = array_pop($days);
}
```

Y en otro archivo de la carpeta "core" del theme llamado timetable.php me encuentro con esta función al principio:

```
public function getDays() {
if (!isset(self::$cache['days'])) {
$days = array();
foreach ($this->get('calendar.period') as $time) {
$object = new VTCore_Wordpress_Objects_Array(array(
'id' => strtolower($time->format('l')),
'timestamp' => $time->getTimeStamp(),
'formatted' => $time->format($this->get('calendar.format')),
'iso' => $time->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'),
'label' => $this->get('days.' . strtolower($time->format('l'))),
));
$days[] = $object;
}
self::$cache['days'] = $days;
}
return self::$cache['days'];
}
```

De ahí creo que genera los días y hay que agregar algo para que salgan español. ¿Estoy bien o me fuí a buscar donde no debía?

Comment: Podrías borrar la caché de wordpress, mediante algún plugin o bien eliminando el contenido de la carpeta `wp-content/cache/`

Comment: A priori, parece que coge los días tal y como los suelta el objeto `Date`, así que para "traducirlos", se me ocurre que puedes montarte un middle

Answer (score 2):

Si efectivamente es allí donde se generan las cadenas de los días, podrías pasar la variable `$days` antes de insertarla de asignar su valor al `self::$cache`.

A reserva de saber los nombres que te está devolviendo, podrías probar con un loop y una simple función de reemplazo así:

```
$days = array_map(function($nombre) {
    return str_replace(
        ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], 
        ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'], 
        $nombre);
}, $days);
```

Si los nombre vienen en mayúsculas o minúsculas, cambia simplemente los textos de origen y de salida.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que modificar al setlocale aquí te lo cuentan muy bien: (https://lachabela.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/fechas-en-espanol-con-php-y-setlocale/) Espero te ayude. Un saludo.